How do I specify https for an express app when serving from AWS?
I've deployed both a frontend react app and backend node/express app on AWS lightsail.
I've configured my frontend to use https using bncert, but I need to make my backend use https now. I added this config to my express app
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt'),
}
  
const server = https.createServer(options, app);

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 5000');
});

However when I go to my website like this: https://myapp.com:5000/api/getcontent Chrome warns me that this app is not secure. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Chrome warns me that this app is not secure. It also tells you why, with a cryptic but important message like net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. Pleas edit your question to include that message and any other relevant error details.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk yeah that's the message I get

I figured out that this is the wrong path:
key: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt'),

For some reason it's what a vhost would use so I thought this would be the right path to the certificates that I createed.
